# Chrome scrolling by it self

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a wierd problem with Chrome. I have some "go to no where links"

```
<a href="#">
```

that change an iframe content and there are more links in the iframe page.

So my problem is that when I click the "go to no where link" on the page and inside the iframe, Chrome automatically scrolls the link position.

Is there somthing I can do to cancel this effect?

Here is one of the contents of the link that is changing the content of the iframe:

```
var isChrome = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") >= 0);
function LoadFrame(url) {
    var oFrame = document.getElementById("iframeBoxID");
    if (isChrome) {
        oFrame.style.visibility = "hidden";
        oFrame.onload = function () {
            oFrame.style.visibility = "visible";
        };
    }
    oFrame.src = url;
}


$("#TestPage1").click(function () {
    LoadFrame("../galleryControlTest/TestPage1.aspx");
    changeFocusToIframe(this);
});
```

Is there somthing I can add to the script that will cancel this effect?
In IE and FireFox this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `return false` to your onlick event.

```
$("#TestPage1").click(function () {
    LoadFrame("../galleryControlTest/TestPage1.aspx");
    changeFocusToIframe(this);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This should work, but I (usually) also have the handler to have an event argument as `function(e) { ... e.preventDefault(); return false; }` just in case

Comment: Yep, return false will cancel the original event, this will effectively prevent the link from reacting like it has been clicked.

Comment: that did the trick :) but i cant accept your answer in 5 min for some reason lol.

Comment: @samy no problemes just remember in 5 minutes ;-) Happy to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the "#", write it just like that : `<a href="">`